# Collada Export Ruins Armature Animation

Tags: animation, collada

I spend some time to find solution but I could not.

There are two pictures below;

1st one from animation runs at blender and the 2nd one from preview application screen shot runs a Collada (dae) export of the same animation.

Why is it so distorted ?

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

The main cause of deformation armatures's origin and object's origin was not the same point. After I changed their origin as the same point deformation is diminished but not completely disappear.

If I can find more I will update the answer.